# How to compute the contentOffset at which the scroll view will halt after deceleration ended?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I need to perform some special things at exactly the position where the scroll view will stop deceleration, but I need to know that position *before* it finished decelerating.

Is there a way to do it, or must I implement my own deceleration logic instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as I know there is no way to predict it before the scrollview actually finish decelerating. I don't know why do you want to predict it but I feel its always wise to wait for it to end the deceleration.

Though you create your own logic I am afraid it would give you the exact value. I wish you luck anyway :-)